# Why does malloc ask for unreasonable amout of memory from sbrk. what can prevent it?

Tags: c, gcc, embedded, malloc, heap-memory

I have a barebone arm controller compiled with the gcc-arm-none-eabi toolchanin.
I notice that asking malloc() for 132 bytes which in turn causes malloc() to call sbrk() twice, first asking for size 152 B and next asking for 4100 B before returning.

Malloc() is in this case called from sprintf(), and it seem that each formatter (%d, %f, ...) allocates its own memory. Repeted use of one identifier does not result in more allocation. It is when %f is used that the 4100 B is allocated.

4 kB is in this case not a problem. But I would like to know that it does not ask for another similar amount.

- Should malloc allocate this much?
- Is there anything I can set to prevent it?
- Should I worry that malloc might ask for even more space (without reason)?

The sbrk code is not the one provided from the toolchain.  malloc is wrapped so I can see what happens.

```
char *_cur_brk;
void *_sbrk_r(struct _reent *reent, ptrdiff_t diff)
{
    void *_old_brk = _cur_brk;
    monitor_printf("_sbrk_r called with size = %d. cur_brk = %p \t", diff, _cur_brk);
    void * ptr;
    ptr = __builtin_return_address(0);
    monitor_printf("Called from %d: %p\t", 0, ptr );
    monitor_printEOL();
    extdiff = diff;

    if ( (_cur_brk + diff ) > _HeapLimit  ) {
        sbrk_error += 1;
        errno = ENOMEM;
        monitor_printf(" failed, cur_brk=%d, HeapLimit=%d", _cur_brk, _HeapLimit);
        monitor_printEOL();
        return (void *)-1;
    }
    sbrk_error = 0;
    _cur_brk += diff;

    monitor_printf("return  %p", _old_brk);
    monitor_printEOL();
    return _old_brk;
}
void * __wrap__malloc_r( struct _reent *reent, size_t size )
{
    void * ret;
    monitor_printf("wrap_malloc_r called with size = %d.", size);
    monitor_printEOL();
    ret = __real__malloc_r( reent, size );
    return ret;
}
```

output of call to malloc(132)

```
wrap_malloc_r called with size = 132.
_sbrk_r called with size = 152. cur_brk = 0x20005f64    Called from 0: 0x801311b 
return  0x20005f64
_sbrk_r called with size = 4100. cur_brk = 0x20005ffc   Called from 0: 0x8013181 
return  0x20005ffc 
Memory allocated at 0x20005f70lling malloc(132)
```

thanks
/johan

Comment: Why would you ever use malloc on a bare metal microcontroller? It doesn't make any sense - an ARM is not a PC. [Read this](http://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/171581/6102).

Comment: @Lundin: Microcontrollers nowadays can have more memory than the original IBM PC. The link you give refers to a microcontroller where `malloc` indeed makes no sense, but you can't just assume that the same holds for joing here.

Comment: @joing: Is this consistent, or just on the first call? `malloc` might set up a 4kB page of bookkeeping on the first call

Comment: @MSalters The amount of memory isn't the reason why it doesn't make sense. The lack of a multi-process desktop operative system is.

Comment: @Lundin: What does that have to do with it? To take an example I worked on, a phone switch definitely isn't a desktop PC, but dynamic memory allocation certainly made sense. There's just a large variety of calls you could have (incoming or outgoing, local or trunk, rerouted, collect call, ...) and it would not be feasible to allocate all memory for all types of calls. I.e. if you could support a 1000 calls, you didn't allocate memory for 1000 incoming calls _plus_ 1000 outgoing calls.

Comment: @MSalters If you could support 1000 calls, why wouldn't you allocate memory statically for exactly 1000 calls? Then design it so that each call could be either an outgoing or incoming call. Your program must be designed so that it can handle the case where all 1000 calls are of the most memory-consuming kind, or otherwise the product wouldn't meet the specification. So I really don't see what problem dynamic allocation would have solved.

Comment: @Lundin: The reason malloc is called is sprintf which calls it, and the 4kB call shows up first time floats is formatted, not next time.

Comment: @MSalters: It might be bookkeeping and that would be OK if I could be sure it does not allocate even more in this range.

Comment: @MSalters Another reason not to use heap-based dynamic memory allocation is fragmentation. A system which is meant to run for months and years must have predictable memory behaviour.

Comment: @joing That's **one** reason not to use the stream-io functions like `printf`, `scanf`, etc. Bare-metal ambedded programming is not like PC-level programming

Answer (score 2):

"Without reason" is a bold claim, I'm sure it's not doing it just to be mean.

What you should do, however, is investigate if you can move to a more embedded-friendly standard library, one that is more careful with memory. It seems its your heap allocation code, i.e. the `malloc()` implementation that's the culprit.

One simple guess is that `malloc()` needs some data structure to keep track of the allocations, and since you're (probably, remember this is a guess!) doing the first allocation as a side-effect of `vsnprintf()`, it has to do that in order to track it.

On more typical desktop/server computer platforms of today, 4 KB is very little memory so no reason to not do the allocation if it's needed by the design. In the embedded space, of course, that's not true.

Personally, I have a local replacement for `vsnprintf()` that does zero heap allocations.

Comment: I guess a local replacement of vsnprintf would be good. What really bugs me is the double call to sbrk when the first really should be enough.  So another solution would be rewriting malloc.